# List files on S3

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I'm getting frustrated by not finding any good explanation on how to list all files in a S3 bucket.

I have this bucket with about 20 images on. All I want to do is to list them. Someone says "just use the S3.list-method". But without any special library there is no S3.list-method. 
I have a S3.get-method, which I dont get to work. Arggh, would appreciate if someone told me how to simply get an list of all files(filenames) from an S3 bucket.

```
val S3files = S3.get(bucketName: String, path: Option[String], prefix: Option[String], delimiter: Option[String])
```

returns an Future[Response]

I dont know how to use this S3.get.
What would be the easiest way to list all files in my S3 bucket?

Answers much appreciated!

Comment: Now you can also use the following dedicated Scala lib: https://github.com/zengularity/benji

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the library here:

https://github.com/Rhinofly/play-s3

You should be able to do something like this:

```
import concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._

val bucket = S3("bucketName")
val result = bucket.list
result.map {
  case Left(error) => throw new Exception("Error: " + x)
  case Right(list) => 
    list.foreach {
        case BucketItem(name, isVirtual) => //...
    }
}
```

You'll have to tweak this a bit in regards to your credentials, but the examples show how to do that.

Answer (score 7):

With Scala you might now want to use Amazon's official [SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) which provides the [`AmazonS3::listObjects`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects-java.lang.String-) method:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing

def keys(bucket: String): List[String] = nextBatch(s3Client.listObjects(bucket))

private def nextBatch(listing: ObjectListing, keys: List[String] = Nil): List[String] = {

  val pageKeys = listing.getObjectSummaries.asScala.map(_.getKey).toList

  if (listing.isTruncated)
    nextBatch(s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing), pageKeys ::: keys)
  else
    pageKeys ::: keys
}
```

---

Note the recursion on `ObjectListing` objects:

Since the listing of keys in a bucket is done by batch (using a pagination system as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#listObjects-java.lang.String-)), only up to the first 1000 keys would be returned by `s3Client.listObjects(bucket).getObjectSummaries.asScala.map(_.getKey)`.

Thus the recursive call in order to get all keys in a bucket by asking for the next page of keys while `ObjectListing::isTruncated` is true.

Beware of memory issues if your bucket is huge though.

---

`s3Client` can be built as such:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.{AmazonS3, AmazonS3ClientBuilder}
import com.amazonaws.auth.{AWSStaticCredentialsProvider, BasicAWSCredentials}

val credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsKey, awsAccessKey)
val s3Client: AmazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build()
```

with these requirements in `build.sbt` and the [latest version](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-bom" % "1.11.391",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3"  % "1.11.391"
)
```

Comment: I can not thank you enough for this answer. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 2):

```
def listS3Files() = Action {
Await.result(S3("bucketName").list, 15 seconds).fold(
{ error => {
  Logger.error("Error")
  Status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
}},
  success => {
    Ok(success.seq.toString())
  }
 )
}
```

Here's my working solution. Thanks to @cmbaxter

Comment: what do I need to import to bring `Action` into scope? Its very hard to google this.

Answer (score 0):

```
val listObjectsRequest: ListObjectsV2Request = new ListObjectsV2Request()
      .withBucketName(bucketName)
      .withPrefix({path of directory})
      .withDelimiter("/")

    val listOfObejct: List[String] = amazonS3.listObjectsV2(listObjectsRequest)
      .getCommonPrefixes
      .asScala
      .toList
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).