# scala - iterate over files in directory and get file name that match a specific string in directory?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a directory with files that look like `abc_00_00.csv , abc_001_00.csv , abc_002_00.csv, def_00_00.csv`

I want only those file which matched user input, i am trying below method but it is not working in spark

```
new File("dbfs:/s3path").listFiles.filter(_.getName.startsWith("abc_*")).foreach(println)
```

error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

is there any way in spark through which i can iterate over match file in foor loop ?

Comment: Your directory does not exist. Also you don't want an asterisk in `startsWith`, just `startsWith("abc_")`.

Comment: sorry for confusion, i am not checking in local dir, i am searching in s3 path

Comment: `File` will not work with s3. You need an aws client for that. Regardless, the reason you get the NPE is because directory does not exist: `.listFiles` returns null in this case .

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the folder may not exist, and also you have no element starting by `abc_*` , wildcards are not allowed here. So please try:

```
new File("C:/dir/").listFiles.filter(_.getName.startsWith("abc_")).foreach(println)
```

If any problem is found, that means your directory does not exists, it may be because of the lowercase c: , try with it in uppercase and check if `dir` exists

In order to be sure, i'll consider checking if the directory exists as follows:

```
val directory = new File("C:/dir/")

if (directory.exists && directory.isDirectory) {
   directory.listFiles.filter(_.getName.startsWith("abc_")).foreach(println)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SCouto for your reply.... my directory is in s3 path, i have check

Comment: new File("dbfs:/spath").listFiles.filter(_.getName.startsWith("abc_*")).foreach(println)

Comment: dbfs is not s3, it should be something as "s3a://..." .., also you still have the wildcard (*), remove it please

Comment: S3 is a whole different story. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342061/list-files-on-s3